# We want to restrict access to our cloud software based on physical sites (homes of staff + our offices) But the IP at these sites don't have static ip

Tags: networking, router, firewall, nginx, dongle

The IPs that are assigned by ISP for staff working from home is dynamic and can change. But we do want to restrict access so that https requests coming from fixed locations like homes of staff and office locations. We do not want staff or others to access the https based software from locations or networks other than those at their homes or at our office. How can that be implemented?

Can we give small physical devices that connect to their internet router or perhaps a usb dongle? OR some special router that can add headers or cookies to the https requests? Or any other way to manage ip based restrictions with dynamic ips?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: we want to restrict access to our cloud software (browser based) based on sites (homes of certain staff plus our offices) But the IP at these sites keep changing since they do not have static ip assigned by isp at those sites.

Comment: Use passwords or digital credentials or VPN or whatever your cloud software accepts.

Comment: we need this protection in addition to standard password based authentication that the software implements. We do not want the staff to use the software from any other site/location other than their residence and from our office

Comment: Yeah, so how do you ensure that they didn't _bring the whole "special router"_ with them when travelling? They could literally carry the USB dongle with them (and optionally lose it in a bus).

Comment: I'd rethink your security model from scratch. This will not work. Your remote workers already have company data on their personal machines. That's bad. Look at something actually secure such as webex, then their data remains *always* in your building & it doesn't matter where they access it from, because it never actually leaves the building.

Comment: Perhaps you could give them a phone with ability to disable location services disabled (by your IT department) and require them to use that to authenticate. My wife's work does that. Not very friendly though...